# Cannot access Ubuntu 14.04 instance's Apache from browser - AWS

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I have following `Security Group` attached to AWS instance.

[image]

I installed Apache When I try to access it from browser I see `This site can’t be reached`

following is some useful info to debug what is issue.

```
root@ip-172-31-31-29:~# netstat -atn |grep :80
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

**EDIT**

Here is updated screenshot of the Security Group.

[image]

Comment: check Ip of you system which you are using to access with browser  . May be your system have IPv4 address .

As Bryce said you only enabled IPV6  on 80 port . may be your system with browser using ipv4

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're allowing IPv6 traffic. Is this what you desire? I would change your security group to allow 0.0.0.0/0 for http.

If you do desire IPv6 I would start with running curl locally and see what it tells you

```
curl -k localhost
```

From there you then should ensure IPTables is properly configured and that SELinux is properly configured.

Comment: so where should I make this change? in security group? which group?

Comment: How you say I am allowing IPv6 traffic? from the command's output?

Comment: Doing curl -k localhost  on the same server  i want to access via browser 
 returns the HTML file located in www root dir. ... (I am SSHed into that server,) only issue is that its not accessible via browser